# AJAX + PHP ¿Como actualizar N navegadores?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

nunca antes he trabajado con AJAX, por lo que decidí hacer un mini chat, super ultra básico.

- Hay un único historial (se guarda en un .txt)
- Se guarda nombre + fecha + hora + mensaje
  Hice que funcionara, pero si tengo 2 navegadores abierto, chateando entre sí, si uno manda un mensaje, hasta que el receptor no mande uno, no puede leer los nuevos mensajes ¿como puedo hacer que ajax actualice todos los navegadores?

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <form method="post">
        <h1>Escriba su mensaje:</h1>
        <input type="text" id="mensaje" placeholder="Escribir mensaje">
        <input type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="enviar_datos_ajax();">
        </form>

        <div id="mostrarmensajes">
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function enviar_datos_ajax(){
        var vMensaje=document.getElementById("mensaje").value;

        var vUrl="code.php";
        $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:vUrl,
        data:{mensaje:vMensaje},
        success:function(datos)
         {
          $("#mostrarmensajes").html(datos);
         }
        }
        )
}
```

**code.php**

```
    <?php
//Se crea la sessión y se establece la zona horaria
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('europe/madrid');
//Definición de variables
$mensaje = $fecha = $hora = $linea = '';

//Se guardan los mensajes
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
            if(!empty($_POST["mensaje"]))
                {
                    $mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
                    $fecha = date('d-m-Y');
                    $hora = date('H:i:s');
                    $linea = $_SESSION['name']. ":" .$mensaje. "(".' '.$fecha. ' '.$hora.")". "\n";
                    //$linea=$mensaje;
                    $bd = fopen("bdmensajeria.txt", "a") or die("No se pudo enviar su mensaje!");
                    fwrite($bd, $linea);
                    fclose($bd);
                    //echo $mensaje;
                }
    }


 //Muestro la charla
// if (isset($_SESSION['nombre'])){header('Location:chat.php?m=logobligatorio');}
   $leer = fopen("bdmensajeria.txt", "r") or die("Error al obtener mensajes del chat, vuelva mas tarde");
   //Linea por linea
   echo "<table bordercolor='#0000FF' cellspacing='10' cellpadding='10'>";
  while(!feof($leer)){
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>". fgets($leer) ."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
   }
   echo "</table>";
   fclose($leer);

?>
```

En realidad index.html le cambié el nombre por chat.html, y creé un index.php que preguntará el nombre y lo almacenara en $_SESSION (para que sepan de donde saco el nombre xD)

Comment: Bienvenido, Carlos. Entiendo que para todo lo que dijiste aún no usas Ajax, cierto? Sería bueno que nos mostraras las partes del código que arman tu chat, a fin de saber en qué parte debiera ir la actualización automática que deseas (que se puede hacer, por ejemplo, con un timer sencillo de Javascript, pero necesitamos saber hasta dónde has llegado con tu desarrollo).

Comment: Gracias por la rápida respuesta. La primera versión del chat hice que la página se recargará cada 10 segundos, por lo que podían apreciar todos los mensajes. En la versión actual he quitado esa línea y hago que se actualice cuando haya un nuevo mensaje (con ajax), voy a poner algo de código.

Comment: Hola, lo que puedes usar son librerias en tiempo real como `web-socket` algunos ejemplos son `socket.io` (su hola mundo es un chat),  `signal-R` con eso es facil hacer un chat, pero no son llamadas ajax convencionales, sino mas bien es una programación adaptada a escuchar eventos.

Comment: Entonces ¿"Ajax" no sirve para lo que yo deseo hacer?

Comment: Sí sirve, pero @RicardoD.Quiroga te sugiere algunas librerías que seguramente te traen todo listo, llegar y usar (yo no las conozco, vale decir, también suelo hacer todo desde cero, jajaja xD).

Comment: Mirando tu código, la primera sugerencia que te hago es que la llamada a `script.js` la debieras hacer después de la llamada a la librería `jquery`, si es que estás usando los métodos de ésta en tu `script.js`. El orden de carga usualmente es importante, no sé si a ti te ha dado problema...

Comment: No me daba problemas, pero acabo de cambiarlo como tu lo sugeriste. Solo funciona cuando doy a "enviar", en el navegador en el que se presiona ese botón, lo que quiero es que cuando haya un nuevo mensaje todos lo puedan leer de forma instantánea. Entiendo y agradezco lo de socket.io luego lo probaré, pero necesito entender el funcionamiento de ajax ¿me ayudan? xD :D

Comment: mira la unica forma, super engorrosa es meter un `timeout` al inicio que cada *x* tiempo llame la funcion recuperar mensajes. AJAX son peticiones asíncronas por lo que antes de realizar una nueva llamada deberias controlar que la anterior se haya completado, en fin   recomende `socket.io` por ser muy sencillo de implementar y funciona de manera excelente. Por cierto otro cuello de botella si es que almacenas las conversaciones es la Base de Datos, bases de datos tipo SQL son malisimas para esta tarea.

Comment: Extracto de una pregunta similar [Get Real Time Data Using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995697/get-realtime-data-using-ajax) Usar ajax no es una buena idea, ya que debe enviar una solicitud al servidor después de cada X segundos para obtener datos, incluso si no hay cambios en el servidor. Hacer esto es más como si estuvieras atacando a tu propio servidor sin saberlo.

Comment: Hola @Carlos, El código que tienes va a funcionar el el navegador que envía al mensaje no así en los demás navegadores, no hay una funcion en ajax que permita recargar otro navegador distinto al que se esta ejecutando, la unica forma que veo es con un `setTimeout` ejecutando una función que pregunte si hay un nuevo mensaje y cargarlo

Comment: Por el momento no tengo mucho tiempo para codificar una respuesta, por eso te dejo este JsFiddle, donde ejemplifiqué un pequeño Timer, que cierto es, puede volver loco a tu navegador, pero ya que estás sólo probando, te sirve para aprender: [Timer Chat](https://jsfiddle.net/9nqbaoon/12/)

Comment: Gracias por tu solución, pero me gustaría considerar otras que no sea forzar al navegador a recargar la página cada X segundos.

Comment: Sí, claro. Entonces sería bueno que probaras las opciones que te han dado de librerías ;) Suerte!